# How would I implement this inverse exponential in lua?

Tags: math, lua, reverse-engineering

```
11 -> 3
10 -> 3.1
9 -> 3.333
8 -> 3.5
7 -> 3.7142857142857
6 -> 4
5 -> 4.4
4 -> 5
3 -> 5.666
2 -> 7
1 -> 10
```

Basically I'm trying to reverse engineer a function for calculating Xp awarded to a player. The first number is what you feed into the function, while the second number is what it returns. After visualizing the returned numbers I figured out that they're an inverse exponential, but I've had no luck in implementing them in lua.

Comment: The function is [10sqrt(n)]/n ≈ 10/sqrt(n); it's not inverse exponential. So you may want to clarify your question, to have a more relevant title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for n = 1, 11 do
   local xp = math.floor(10 * n^.5)/n
   print(n, xp)
end
```

Output:

```
1   10
2   7
3   5.6666666666667
4   5
5   4.4
6   4
7   3.7142857142857
8   3.5
9   3.3333333333333
10  3.1
11  3
```

Comment: Nice detective work. Not sure why this was downvoted (always weird to see an accepted answer with negative score).